# iFrame embed - DOMException - Play request interupted by a call to pause

Tags: html, iframe, domexception

I am trying to embed 2 bandcamp embedded players into a HTML page like this...

https://jsfiddle.net/w458a5j2/

```
<iframe style="border: 0; width:100%;max-width: 350px; height: 470px;" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=2201204171/size=large/bgcol=ffffff/linkcol=0687f5/tracklist=false/transparent=true/" seamless></iframe>

<iframe style="border: 0; width: 350px; height: 470px;" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=755152323/size=large/bgcol=ffffff/linkcol=0687f5/tracklist=false/transparent=true/" seamless><a href="http://samiyam.bandcamp.com/album/animals-have-feelings">Animals Have Feelings by Samiyam</a></iframe>
```

They are working correctly but I have found a bug, if you click play on one and then quickly press play on the other video then they both stop playing and I see this in the console...

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()
```

Anyone experienced this before with Bandcamp embeds?

UPDATE

Have also noticed the same thing happens on Bandcamps website itself when they have multiple embedded players - https://daily.bandcamp.com/2018/01/11/contemporary-mpc-albums-list/

Comment: _“if you click play on one and then quickly press play on the other”_ - sounds to me like one of those typical issues that only the developer of the site “provokes”, but that will likely hardly ever occur when a real user is using the site ...

Comment: Perhaps, but i think it can also be replicated if the user is on a slow connection and the audio hasn't actually started playing yet